# How to read a Common Property with Apache POI HSMF

Tags: java, outlook, apache-poi

I'm trying to extract the field BillingInformation from an Outlook .msg file using POI hsmf, but every time I get a ChunkNotFoundException.  I've verified in Outlook that there is content in the field.

```
public class MessageReader {
    private static final int SUBJECT_CHUNK = 0x0037;
    private static final int BILLING_INFORMATION_CHUNK = 0x00008535;
    public static void main(String[] argv) {
        try {
            MAPIMessage mapiMessage = new MAPIMessage("MessageWithBillingInformation.msg");
            System.out.println(mapiMessage.getStringFromChunk(new StringChunk(SUBJECT_CHUNK, true)));
            System.out.println(mapiMessage.getStringFromChunk(new StringChunk(BILLING_INFORMATION_CHUNK, true)));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        } catch (ChunkNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }
    }
}
```

All the documentation I've found lists 0x00008535 as the right ID for Billing Information:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765867.aspx

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure the chunk is in the root? It could well be stored underneath one of the other sections, which would explain why the chunk can't be found. I'd suggest you try with org.apache.poi.poifs.dev.POIFSLister and org.apache.poi.hsmf.dev.HSMFDump to check exactly where it lives

Comment: HSMFDump lists it under the "Chunks" section, without any other name.  But idName it lists as "(unknown)" based on being equal to MAPIProperty.UNKNOWN.

Comment: Can you see it in the POIFSLister? (The chunk id and type should be included in the name)

Comment: Ah, thanks a lot! Converting the HSMFDump's decimal-formatted chunkId to hexadecimal, 0x800A, shows it in POIFSLister's list of chunks.  Using that in the above code gives me the contents of the Billing Information field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a chunkID of 0x800A works for reading the Billing Information field, so the code looks like this:

```
public class MessageReader {
private static final int SUBJECT_CHUNK = 0x0037;
private static final int BILLING_INFORMATION_CHUNK = 0x800A;
public static void main(String[] argv) {
    try {
        MAPIMessage mapiMessage = new MAPIMessage("MessageWithBillingInformation.msg");
        System.out.println(mapiMessage.getStringFromChunk(new StringChunk(SUBJECT_CHUNK, true)));
        System.out.println(mapiMessage.getStringFromChunk(new StringChunk(BILLING_INFORMATION_CHUNK, true)));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    } catch (ChunkNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
}
```

}